# Generating large openpyxl file django

Tags: python, django

I am using django and openpyxl to export reports on button click.  However, one of my reports is very large (about 3.5MB and 150k rows of data with 30+ columns) and when I try and run the openpyxl file generation I get

```
504 Gateway Time-out 
The server didn't respond in time.
```

Is there anyway I can prevent the django view from timing out? Perhaps something I can add to the python in the view to allow for extra processing time?  It doesn't matter if it takes a minute or two.

I have tried openpyxl Write-only mode and it still times out. I think it is also worth noting that I am using apache

Here is my code:

```
wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

# Adds headers
ws.append(data['headers'][1:])


# Add data to 'RawData'
for row in data['data']:
    ws.append(row[1:])

file_name = str(report_name).replace(' ', '_') + "_export.xlsx"
response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{0}"'.format(file_name)
return response
```

Comment: Best thing is to find an async way of doing this, you're opening your server to DDoS by allowing long running processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the `timeout` for **Apache** in the ***httpd.conf***. Use [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

From the official doc of Django I found [Streaming Of Large Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) which is the suitable answer for you,

> When dealing with views that generate very large responses, you might
>   want to consider using Django’s StreamingHttpResponse instead. For
>   example, by streaming a file that takes a long time to generate you
>   can avoid a load balancer dropping a connection that might have
>   otherwise timed out while the server was generating the response.

In that example they are using `csv` but, I think you can change the `content_type="text/csv"` to some other format to make it suitable for you

Comment: I looked into this.  Excel files are technically zip files and you can do a streaming response with zip files.